# Undefined Reference to Class

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've been looking for ~30-45 minutes now and have checked for typos, etc. This is my first time coding in C++ after a long time, so the syntax is a little hard to take. I'm currently making the base classes for my project and so the code is really simple at the moment.

**Server.h**

```
    /*
 * Server.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 28, 2017
 *      Author: Jon
 */

#ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

class Server {
public:
    Server();
    virtual ~Server();
    static Server* getInstance();

private:
    static Server* instance;
};


#endif /* SERVER_H_ */
```

**Server.cpp**

```
/*
 * Server.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 28, 2017
 *      Author: Jon
 */

#include "Server.h"

Server::Server() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Server::~Server() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

Server* Server::getInstance() {
    if (!Server::instance)
        Server::instance = new Server();
    return Server::instance;
}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Server.h"
#include <assert.h>

Server* server;

int main() {
    server = Server::getInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently running into an issue with ...

**Undefined reference to Server::instance**

Is how I'm accessing my static member incorrect?

Comment: Your question will be meaningless to future readers if it keeps changing especially after users have answered it.

Comment: Why do you return a pointer and not a reference?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry, I don't code much in C++. What would change if I did by reference?

Comment: @JonathanNguyen: In C++, the guideline is to use a reference if you can and a pointer if you must. So there's just no reason *not* to use a reference here. The pointer accomplishes nothing and prevents the compiler from noticing rare errors at the call site (e.g. accidentally calling `delete` on it, or accidentally comparing it with `nullptr`). An important difference to Java is that you do not have the distinction between pointers and references there! Java does not have what C++ calls "references", and its "references" are more like pointers in C++.

Comment: @JonathanNguyen: Oh, and note that the word "reference" used by the linker is yet another meaning! :) I just mention that because your question originally was about linker errors about "undefined references".

Comment: By the way, another possible mistake is that you have made the destructor of your Singleton class `virtual`. `virtual` only makes sense for classes to be derived from, and deriving from Singleton classes is a questionable design choice. OTOH, the Singleton pattern itself is a questionable design choice (but that's the same in Java and other programming languages).

Comment: @ChristianHackl ah my bad! Eclipse auto generated that so I should modify it. As for you explanation on references I'll keep that in mind and make the appropriate changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getInstance` is a static member function of class `Server` which belongs to the namespace `Server`, so you should use it in `main()` as:

```
instance = Server::Server::getInstance();
//         ~~~~~~~~
```

And you should change the definition of `Server::instance` inside namespace `Server` from

```
Server* instance;         // a non-member variable in namespace Server
```

to

```
Server* Server::instance; // the definition of the static member variable Server::instance
```

**EDIT**

After the the edit (removing the namespace) the original usage is correct now. The only problem is the definition of the static member `Server::instance`. You should add it in the `Server.cpp` as

```
Server* Server::instance; // the definition of the static member variable Server::instance
```

Comment: Ouch, I just found out Eclipse made those namespaces upon class creation. I removed the namespaces now. Is the original way correct?

Comment: @JonathanNguyen If you don't need the namespace and remove it, the original usage is correct. Note  you need to fix other relevant code too.

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks for the patient help. It's an awkward transition coming from Java!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `Server::getInstance()`:

Change:

```
Server* getInstance() {
```

To:

```
Server* Server::getInstance() {
```

@songyuanyao is right, `Server::getInstance()` is static, and `Server` is in the `Server` namespace. To call `getInstance()` use:

```
Server::Server::getInstance()
```

Comment: I still have the same issue + 1 more now.